# c# System.NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly ADO.Net Oracle UDT

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, ado.net

c# System.NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly Oracle UDT when calling stored procedure ADO.Net.

It works with Oracle 10g Client, while not working with deployment environment where oracle 12c client is installed.

- Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.111.7.20 - working.
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.121.1.0 - not working.

Comment: Usually the version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` has to match exactly the version of the Oracle Client. Can you please verify which DLL has been loaded (`Debug.WriteLine(con.GetType().Assembly.FullName);`). What is the version of the database? (use `select * from v$version;`)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes if its different but still both are oracle.dataaccess clients, it should work, because normal stored procedures without UDTs are working fine. only UDTs parameters SP are throwing this exception.